# Symfony convert in string URL

Tags: php, symfony, url

I print an integer variable converted to a string with this method:

```
public function __toString(){
    return strval($this->id);
}
```

I print this in my twig file and it work good but I have a problem when my variable is being put in a URL path like this:

```
<a href="{{ path('profilo_secondlevel', {'uid': user.idUserReferenced}) }}">{{ user.idUserReferenced }}</a>
```

My URL see it that way:

```
 <a href="/app_dev.php/profilo/secondo-livello?uid%5B__isInitialized__%5D=1">73</a>
```

I read about this problem and this is called percent encoding and is used in encoding special characters in the URL parameter values.
But I want my id number in the URL...

How can I do?

CODE OF routing.yml

---

```
    ################################################################################
 #                               /profile/secondo_livello                                    #
```

#

```
 profilo_secondlevel:
host:      "{_locale}.{domain}"
locales:  { it: "/profilo/secondo-livello.{_format}", fr: "/profilo/secondo-livello.{_format}", de: "/profilo/secondo-livello.{_format}" }
defaults:  { _locale: "%locale%", domain: "%domain%", _format: "html", _controller: DtEcBundle:Profile:secondLevel }
requirements:
    _locale: "it|fr|de"
    domain:  "%domain%"
    _format:  "html|json"

 profilo_secondlevel_www.it:
path:      /profilo/secondo-livello/{uid}.{_format}
host:      "www.{domain}"
defaults:  { _locale: "%locale%", _format: "html", _controller: DtEcBundle:Profile:secondLevel }
requirements:
    _locale: "%locale%"
    domain:  "%domain%"
    _format:  "html|json"
  profilo_secondlevel_nowww.it:
path:      /profilo/secondo-livello/{uid}.{_format}
host:      "{domain}"
defaults:  { _locale: "%locale%",  _format: "html", _controller: DtEcBundle:Profile:secondLevel }
requirements:
    _locale: "%locale%"
    domain:  "%domain%"
    _format:  "html|json"
```

Comment: Could you please add the code of the routing.yml (or the controller annotation) where you've defined the `profilo_secondlevel` route? It should be something like `/profilo/secondo-livello/{uid}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have defined a controller which serves the `profilo_secondlevel` route, you would have a routing configuration as follows:

<kbd>**app/config/routing.yml**</kbd>

```
profilo_secondlevel:
  host:      "{_locale}.{domain}"
  path:      /profilo/secondo-livello/{uid}.{_format}
  defaults:  { _locale: "%locale%", domain: "%domain%", _format: "html", _controller: DtEcBundle:Profile:secondLevel }
  requirements:
    _locale: "it|fr|de"
    domain:  "%domain%"
    _format:  "html|json"
```

Then you could use the following template code on your twig template:

```
<a href="{{ path('profilo_secondlevel', {'uid': user.idUserReferenced}) }}">
{{ user.idUserReferenced }}
</a>
```

and it should result in an URL like that: `/profilo/secondo-livello/73.html`.

Comment: I edit my post and add my routing.yml but with your solution nothing has changed @sentenza

Comment: I added the path to `routing.yml`. It is more or less the same as the `profilo_secondlevel_www.it` route.